# Как заставить Webpack dev server перезагружать страницу при исправлении ошибок?

Tags: webpack

Всем привет!
У меня такая проблема: если в js файле я допущу ошибку, то она улетит в браузер и после этого вебпак не будет перезагружать страницу, даже если ошибка исправлена. Как можно это поправить так, чтобы при наличии ошибки она падала в overlay, а при исправлении страница перезагружалась?

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const target = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'browserslist' : 'web';

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js')
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].min.js'
  },
  target: target,
  mode: mode,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    open: true,
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.pug'),
      scriptLoading: 'blocking'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.min.css'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: 'pug-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

index.js

```js
import './style.sass';

import module from './module.js';

const app = document.querySelector('#app');

app.textContent = module('Hello from webpack test');

console.log('Hello');
```

Если изменить app.textContent на pp.textContent, то в браузер падает ошибка (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: pp), если поправить обратно, то страница не перезагружается без ручной перезагрузки

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Если у кого-то похожая проблема, что ошибка из js блокирует перезагрузку дев-сервера, то скорее всего дело в webpack-dev-server, обновил его до ^4.0.0-beta.3 и все заработало, также в overlay появились детальные описания ошибок